# How to plot the individual row values using time series in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In column-1 (Data_1) there are 6 rows i am trying to plot each row  individually w.r.t time.I want to plot using   Time series in matplotlib. I don't how to use time series for plotting. I don't know how to pass time  information for plotting:

reference graph

[image]

Can someone tell me how to pass this information correctly.

How Can I plot time on the x axis and the rows on the y-axis using Matplotlib?Thanks in Advance

```
 Time;    Data_1;
0.000000;  2389;-r1
0.002778;  2381;-r2
0.005556;  2372;-r3
0.008333;  2360;-r4
0.011111;  2355;-r5
0.013889;  2351;-r6
```

```py
sys.__stdout__ = sys.stdout
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

df = pd.read_csv('tst.txt', delimiter='\t')

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        x1 = j
        y1 =row[0]
        print(x1,y1)

df.plot(x="x1",y="y1",ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I want to use for loop for time  in x axis :for x in (0,10000) for every row.I want to plot graph x in time all individual row(r1 to r6)  values in y axis one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance could be improved by not relying on pandas `plot` function, but depending on your data, this could work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tst.csv', delimiter=';')   
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
def animate(i):
    plt.cla()
    df.iloc[:i+1,:].plot(x='Time', ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim(df.Time.min(), df.Time.max()) # prevents pandas from changing xlimits if desired

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(df.index), interval=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying. Are you trying to plot one column at a time? Or row by row as I did? I don't understand what the final graph should look like

Comment: yes i want to plot one one(Data_1) column at time time and i want to read how Data_1 values and I want to see how those values updating on the plot graph on step by step ..